# Wordpress plugin files do not load on custom theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a problem where custom theme does not load plugins files on custom theme page.

When switching to default theme plugins files get loaded correctly on the same page.
I am not sure if I am missing something as all action hooks that I could find mandatory are included.
Any guidance or help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Custom theme page setup is as follows:

header.php contents:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<?php wp_head();?>
</head>
```

page-custom.php contents:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<body>
<?php
// content
$content_post = get_post(125); // 125 equals id of the custom page
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;

// footer
get_footer();
?>
```

footer.php contents:

```
<?php
wp_footer();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look through the plugin's code to see what it's actually hooking into and figuring out if it's something missing from the template your theme is loading on a certain page.